# Remove ID from URL in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to remove the ID from the URL in ASP.net 2010.
I tried to search in the net but I didn't get a clear solution.
Can you help me please or send me links for a clear solution to understand and apply in my website?

I have a simple datalist in the page Architecture.aspx. this datalist get info from SqlDataSource1 (see code below). 
When I press in the LinkButton (Image1), a new page (ViewProject) opens, in the URL I have (http://localhost:51550/Portfolio/ViewProject.aspx?ID=1). I dont want to show the ID:

```
 <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="ID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" style="margin-right: 0px"
        EnableViewState="false">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle = "None" Height="250px" Width="200px">
            <table id="Table1" runat="server" style="height: 50px"> 
            <tr >   
            <td style="color: #000000; width: 75%; font-weight: lighter" align="center">
            <asp:LinkButton Width="145px" Height ="200px"  ID="Image1" runat="server"  CommandName="ViewDetails" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>'  OnCommand = "Click_LinkButton1" >
            <div class ="pic">
            <asp:Image ID = "im1" runat="server" ImageUrl= '<%# Eval("mainPic")%>' Width="150px" Height ="200px"  BorderWidth="0px"  />
            </div>
            </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
            <td style="width: 75%; font-weight: lighter; padding-left:19px">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title") %>' ForeColor="Gray" Font-Names="Lucida Sans Unicode" Font-Size="12px"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
        </asp:Panel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    </div>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PortfolioConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [title], [mainPic] FROM [Project]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void Click_LinkButton1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "ViewProject.aspx?";
    url += "ID=" + e.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Comment: I hear the backspace key works pretty well. You should probably show some code so that we can better understand what it is that you want to do. Right now, I don't understand your question.

Comment: You can create a session variable named ID and set its value to be accessed on other pages

Comment: What's wrong with passing it in the URL? Seems like that's the cleanest way to do it. Session could run into issues if you're opening multiple pages at the same time.

Comment: where should I declare the session variable ? in global.asax? sorry for bothering you.. I am somehow beginner in asp.net

Comment: yes it is the cleanest way to do but I think it is more professional to remove  the ID.

Comment: @Hadil No, it is not more professional to remove the ID. Let's say someone bookmarks a particular project on the `ViewProject.aspx` page. Now the bookmark won't lead to their project, and may even result in a NullReferenceException, especially if you use haraman's code as is. It's also more difficult to share that URL with a colleague. It's better to include the ID in the URL. You don't have to pass it as query string though. You can configure routing so that the URL looks like : `example.com/ViewProject/987`. Look at Stack Overflow URL's.

Comment: @mason thank u for the clarification. If I add the code below I think it will solve the pbm no? if (Session["ID"] == null){ string url = "Architecture.aspx";Response.Redirect(url);} if not,I can display again the ID.

Comment: @Hadil It will solve the potential NullReferenceException issue. But it's still not a great solution because you can't bookmark a specific project, and you can't share the URL to a specific project with others. And if your session expires while you were on a specific project page and you refresh, then you'll be taken to a different page. It's not the standard practice, and it will lead to a bad user experience. Best to leave the ID in the URL.

Comment: Ok i will leave the ID in the URL thank you very much @mason

Comment: @Hadil No problem. Take a look at the [routing page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/routing) I mentioned in my answer. When you said earlier that it "wasn't professional" to include the ID in the URL, I'm thinking you meant "it looks ugly". Learning how routing works in ASP.NET will help you clean it up so you can get a nice, clean, [hackable](http://blog.mastermaq.ca/2007/03/20/clean-amp-hackable-urls/) URL (hackable being a good thing meaning it's easy to work with, not the bad meaning of hackable).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as

```
protected void Click_LinkButton1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "ViewProject.aspx";
    Session("ID") = e.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

and can access it as on the page load event of another page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    String strID = Session("ID").ToString;
}
```

To learn more about sessions visit [asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/), MSDN Article [ASP.NET Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and [How to: Read Values from Session State](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: I tried to add session("ID") but I have the message :The name Session does not exist in the current context

Comment: thank you I tried session.add("ID", e.Command.Argument) and it works

Comment: What happens if someone comes to this page directly without clicking on that link?

Comment: It's the decision of the developer, what he wants to show if the ID is not available. redirect to the proper page or display all available options or anything else as he wants it to be

Answer (score 0):

haraman's implementation is not good. His implementation didn't check for missing "ID" in the session. That means if someone navigates directly to the page without having clicked on that link button, they're going to get a NullReferenceException. Why would they navigate directly there? Perhaps they bookmarked it. Or they refresh the page after their session expires. Or they share the link with a coworker.

Instead, you **should** pass the ID in the URL. There's nothing unprofessional about it. It's certainly preferable to the problems that not including it would cause. If you're concerned about the looks, you can make it look nicer. You don't have to utilize query string.

Query string example:

```
example.com/ViewProject.aspx?id=987
```

ASP.NET has a concept of [routing](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/routing), which you can utilize in your application for a clean URL. Using routing, your URL can look like this:

```
example.com/ViewProject/987
```

And with some additional tools, you can make it search engine/user friendly (Stack Overflow does this):

```
example.com/ViewProject/987/My-Fancy-Project
```

Comment: As I replied in comment it will be the decision of the developer what he wants to do, we can not force him to use things our way, also it may not always be necessary to show the IDs.

Comment: Now what will be your solution if he doesn't want to show `987` in the url, OP wants to hide the IDs at all

Comment: @haraman Then in your code, you should show how to check to make sure the value exists in the session before accessing it. But that still doesn't address the other points I raised that make your implementation undesirable. Hiding the ID is not a good idea, there's no reason to do that.

Comment: That was not the main issue OP asked for. His motive was not to show ID in the URL, shifting from one url pattern to other is NOT a solution because that still displays the ID

Comment: @haraman Yes, I clearly understood that. But I'm saying that there's nothing wrong with displaying it. You can disagree with me, that's fine.

Comment: thank you for the clarification mason I will try to manage this.

Comment: I added the code below I think it will solve the pbm no?  if (Session["ID"] == null){ string url = "Architecture.aspx";Response.Redirect(url);}

Comment: @Hadil If you're dead set on not showing the ID in the URL, then go ahead. I don't recommend it. `Response.Redirect("~/Architecture.aspx");` Best to use application root relative paths